# Ant XMLTASK insert a node if it doesn't exist already

Tags: xml, ant, xmltask

I have a task to insert an XML node into an existing XML file, only if the node doesn't exist already. I manage the insert just fine, however I can't find that missing if-not functionality

> ```
> <xmltask source="shared.xml" dest="shared.xml" outputter="simple:3">
>    <insert path="/sharedobjects[last()]">
>       <![CDATA[
>       <connection>   
>          <name>MY CONNECTION</name>
>       </connection>
>       ]]>
>    </insert>
> </xmltask>
> ```

If I run this multiple times, of course I will have multiple MY CONNECTION in the xml file. I would like to make a check so that I insert only if the desired connection is not already in the file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this method works as well.

```
<xmltask source="shared.xml" dest="shared.xml" outputter="simple:3">

   <copy path="/sharedobjects/connection[name/text()='MY CONNECTION']/name/text()"
         property="XML_EXISTS_ALREADY" />

   <insert path="/sharedobjects[last()]" unless="XML_EXISTS_ALREADY">
      <![CDATA[
      <connection>   
         <name>MY CONNECTION</name>
      </connection>
      ]]>
   </insert>
</xmltask>
```

NOTE: xmltask's copy task only allows you to store attributes or text nodes in properties. Thus it is necessary to specify `/name/text()` at the end of the path argument for `<copy>` (even though the existence we really care about is the whole `<connection>` node, not its child's text).

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve my problem. It's more or less a workaround. The solution is a delete then insert method

```
<xmltask source="shared.xml" dest="shared.xml" outputter="simple:3">
   <remove path="/sharedobjects/connection[name/text()='MY CONNECTION']"/>
   <insert path="/sharedobjects[last()]">
      <![CDATA[
      <connection>   
         <name>MY CONNECTION</name>
      </connection>
      ]]>
   </insert>
</xmltask>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Ant conditions (not sure if all existed when the question was asked):

```
<if>
    <not>
        <resourcecontains 
            resource="shared.xml" 
            substring="&gt;MY CONNECTION&lt;name&gt;" />
    </not>
<then>
    <xmltask 
...
    </xmltask>
</then>
```